# Reference on an 2D-Array-Element

Tags: java, arrays, reference

```
public class ReferenceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] names = {{"George","Hampton"},{"Marc", "Empten"},{"Levin", "Lian"}};

        Object oneperson; //Reference to one object of the 2D Array

        oneperson = names[1]; 

        //Output should be Marc Empten
        System.out.println(oneperson.toString()); //[Ljava.lang.String;@11890d

    }
}
```

Is it possible to create such a reference in java? So I can save an array-element(

> {"Marc","Empten"}

)  from the array?

So I can use only the oneperson variable to give out the "Marc Empten"?
I have no Idea how to realise this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just print an array use `Arrays.toString()` method. But the better approach her would be to make a class Name which hold both parts. Then use an array list to store the names. Like

```
class Name{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + firstName + ", " + lastName
                + "}";
    }
    // Getters & Setters
}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Name> names = new ArrayList<Name>(Arrays.asList(new Name[] { new Name("George","Hampton"), new Name("Marc", "Empten"), new Name("Levin", "Lian")}));
        System.out.println(names.get(1)); // Prints {Marc, Empten}

    }
}
```

Comment: so i must always use names.get(number) i wanna use a "object" like feuerball it did

Comment: This is almost the same as `names[number]`. Lists have the benefit that you have no constraints in the size.

Comment: List is basically an array underneath the covers. So its similar to feuerball number except it can grow as an when you add items. I didnt full understand what you meant by "i wanna use a object". Did you mean you need to do this as an array?

Comment: no i want to have a reference object like evry other variable for explizit one element of an array or arraylist...

Comment: Yes. That what the indexing does. It returns the element at index 1. Which is equivalent to `Name oneperson = names.get(1);` or you could like `Object oneperson = names.get(1);`.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write something like this:

```
public class ReferenceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An array of arrays of Strings
        String[][] names = {{"George","Hampton"},{"Marc", "Empten"},{"Levin", "Lian"}};
        // An array of Strings
        String[] marc = names[1]; 
        //Output is Marc Empten
        System.out.println(marc[0] + " " + marc[1]);
    }
}
```

This only works if you know for sure that the inner arrays always contain 2 elements. If not you would have to use a loop to print the name for example (note that the last name has 3 parts):

```
final String[][] names =
    { { "George", "Hampton" }, { "Marc", "Empten" }, { "Levin", "Lian" }, { "John", "James", "Rambo" } };

for (final String[] name : names) {
    for (final String partial : name) {
        System.out.print(partial);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[])oneperson));
```

Comment: This does not work because `oneperson` is an `Object` and not an array.

Comment: Additionally it would print `[Marc, Empten]` if it was working.

Comment: with a cast this is possible :

Comment: Added Cast to an array